# Reply to email other than from/reply-to field

Tags: email, sendgrid

My system sends emails on behalf of my users (each user has customers).

When a customer replies to that email, it should reply to my app email instead so I can utilise the inbound parse functionality.

However, I want to display the user's email in the from/reply-to field. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

`from` and `reply-to` are not the same thing. Send from the user's address in the `from` field, then use your app's email in the `reply-to`.

Comment: Is there a way to configure it so it my app is in the reply-to field, but the user sees the other email instead?

Comment: No, that's not possible.